# Can Django collectstatic overwrite old files?

Tags: python, css, django, debian, deb

In my deb postinst file:

```
PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
PYTHON_VERSION=`$PYTHON -c 'import sys; print sys.version[:3]'`
SITE_PACKAGES=/opt/pkgs/mypackage/lib/python$PYTHON_VERSION/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH=$SITE_PACKAGES
echo "collect static files"
$PYTHON manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

> When I run 'dpkg -i mypackage.deb' to install the package, no problem.
>
> When I run 'dpkg -i mypackage.deb' to **re-install the package, old
> css files unchanged**.
>
> When I changed '$PYTHON manage.py collectstatic
> --noinput ' to '$PYTHON manage.py collectstatic --noinput -c' and run 'dpkg -i mypackage.deb' to **re-install the package**, the error is
> following: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/opt/pkgs/myporject/static'

Any idea?

**Can Django collectstatic overwrite old files?**

Comment: I'm confident it can. The error is probably elsewhere. Have you tried to experiment with it without using `deb` and see what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Added here, maybe someone will have same problems with mine.)
Yes.

The timestamp of css files in /opt/pkgs/mypropject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mypropject-py2.7.egg/myapp/static/css (directory A) is the time when package building finished, not the time when css files installed.

But the timestamp of css files in /opt/pkgs/myporject/static (directory B) is the time of installation.

That is why collectstatic sometimes cannot overwrite my old css files (cannot copy some css files from directory A to directory B).